# Given a date, select all the week numbers that month contains

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an ApEx application for tracking working hours. 
I have a view that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW HOURSDAYS
AS SELECT
 (MAX("TO_X") - MIN("FROM_X"))*24 - 
 (max(case when PROJECT_ID = 999 then to_x else to_date('01012000','DDMMYYYY') end) -
  max(case when PROJECT_ID = 999 then from_x else to_date('01012000','DDMMYYYY') end))*24 AS TIME_SPENT,
 DAY,
 PERSON_ID
 FROM ATTENDANCE_HOURS
 GROUP BY PERSON_ID, DAY
 ORDER BY DAY DESC
```

I need the sum of hours per week. So I have this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DAY,'IW'), MIN(DAY), MAX(DAY), SUM(TIME_SPENT)
FROM HOURSDAYS
WHERE PERSON_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ATTENDANCE_PEOPLE WHERE MAIL_SSO = V('APP_USER') AND ROLE = 0) AND
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DAY) = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE(:P100_DATE_PICKER,'DD-MON-RR')) 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DAY,'IW')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(DAY,'IW') ASC
```

And now the fun begins: I have a page item P100_DATE_PICKER and I need to display only those weeks that have > 0 days that belong to the month to which belongs the day I've picked using the date picker.
For example, for 1.1.2015 I want only weeks 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 displayed. 24.3.2015: 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.

If anyone is interested in why would I do that, it is for validation - number of work hours per week cannot exceed 20/32, depends on what type of contract do you have.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this: `24.3.2015: 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.` There are five Sundays and five Mondays in March so why would you display six weeks?

Comment: @DavidFaber Week 9 is from 2015-02-23 to 2015-03-01, so partly in March. Week 14 is from 2015-03-30 to 2015-04-05, so also partly in March. The requirement (as I understand it) is to show all the weeks partly or wholely in the desired month, and to show all data from those weeks. So for March show the data from 2015-02-23 to 2015-04-05 grouped by those 6 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
where day >= trunc(trunc(TO_DATE(:P100_DATE_PICKER,'DD-MON-RR'), 'MM'),'IW')
  and day <  trunc(last_day(TO_DATE(:P100_DATE_PICKER,'DD-MON-RR')),'IW') + 7
```

The first line starts by `trunc` to `MM`, which gives you the first day of the month of your date. Then `trunc` again to `IW` gives you the date of the monday in the week that contains the first day of month.

The second line uses `last_day` to get the last day of the month of your date. Then `trunc` to `IW` gets the monday of *that* week, and adding 7 days get the monday *after*. Then by using `<` rather than `<=` you get the desired result.

Also I suggest you do not group and order by `TO_CHAR(DAY,'IW')` but instead use `TRUNC(DAY,'IW')` for your grouping and ordering. Otherwise you can get into problems around new year, because your code for example when showing the weeks for December 2014 would have to show 49 to 52 of year 2014 as well as week 1 of year 2015. If you use `TO_CHAR` that week 1 would be wrongly sorted before weeks 49 to 52.

Similarly do not use `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ...)` or even `TO_CHAR(...,'YYYY')` when you are working with ISO weeks. Because the date '2014-12-31' belongs to ISO week 1 year 2015, there is a special date format string `'IYYY'` which gives the correct year for the ISO week. Try it out and see the difference between `'YYYY'` and `'IYYY'`.

Answer (score 1):

This will not answer all your questions. This is the quick example of week calculation from a given date according to the subject line of your question. Pls copy/paste to see results. Also, here's the link to check the week numbers:

http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php

```
SELECT given_date
 , end_date
 , TRUNC(calc_start_date, 'iw')                  wk_starts  
 , TRUNC(calc_start_date, 'iw') + 7 - 1/86400    wk_ends 
 , TO_CHAR(calc_start_date, 'iw')                wk_number
 , calc_start_date
FROM 
(
 SELECT trunc(sysdate, 'mm')                     given_date
 , trunc(sysdate, 'mm')-7 + LEVEL*7 AS      calc_start_date
 , Last_Day(trunc(SYSDATE, 'mm'))           end_date
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ROUND((trunc(last_day(sysdate)) - trunc(sysdate, 'mm')+7)/7) -- number of weeks --
)
/
GIVEN DATE  END DATE    WK_STARTS     WK_ENDS                 WK NUMBER
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/2015    1/31/2015   12/29/2014    1/4/2015  11:59:59 PM   01
1/1/2015    1/31/2015   1/5/2015      1/11/2015 11:59:59 PM   02
1/1/2015    1/31/2015   1/12/2015     1/18/2015 11:59:59 PM   03
1/1/2015    1/31/2015   1/19/2015     1/25/2015 11:59:59 PM   04
1/1/2015    1/31/2015   1/26/2015     2/1/2015  11:59:59 PM   05
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve the last part is to have a calendar table that has the following columns

Date, Day eg Mon, Month, Quarter, Year, WeekNo

Then for a given date you can simply select all the weeks that belong to the month.

This allows you to define weekNo  so that it fits in with company circumstances. Eg occasionally you may get a 53 week year, especially if they operate 4-4-5 accounting periods

Comment: That can be useful, yes. For the particular question it would entail *first* selecting the weeks that belong to the month, and *then* selecting all the dates that belong to those weeks (as some of those dates will belong to either the previous or the following month, and they also need to be included in order to get all the work hours of the weeks displayed.)

Comment: So you add a month code column which contains yyyymm. So when you pick the Month it returns the yyyymm code and you then look up the weeks that belong to the month

Answer (score 0):

```
with days as (
  select 
      to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date('2015-03-24', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'month'), 'WW')) w1, 
      to_number(to_char(last_day(to_date('2015-03-24', 'yyyy-MM-dd')), 'WW')) w2 
    from dual)
select w1+level-1 week from days 
  connect by level <= w2-w1+1
```

Subquery `days` gives minimum and maximum week, query with `connect by` returns numbers between these values. Please replace example date with :P100_DATE_PICKER.